# that, self or me — which one to prefer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, this

While coding JavaScript sometimes you store the reference of object `this` in a local variable for different purposes (to set proper scope, to help code obfuscators, etc.). There are coders who prefer aliasing `this` to `that` to make it obvious its intention. Other guys use `self` since it's pointing to the object itself. I even saw source codes where `me` held the reference and it still makes sense. Certainly there are other ones.

Which one should I prefer? Is there a convention on which to use or is it only the matter of taste.

Comment: Note that programming background seems to be a major (the main?) factor–those that use(d) Smalltalk or Python, or learned from those that used them, tend to use 'self'.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I, personally, use `that`, but anything else that's clear is fine.

I wouldn't use `self` because the global variable/`window`-property `self` already exists as a reference to `window`. Although it's totally useless (so no-one is likely to care that you're shadowing it), it slightly increases the risk of silly errors going unnoticed:

```
var se1f= this;         // misspelled (perniciously). or maybe you just forgot to write line
onclick= function() {
    self.foo= 1;        // whoops, just wrote to `window`!
};
```

whereas:

```
var that= this;
onclick= function() {
    that.foo= 1;        // error thrown
};
```

Slightly contrived, but JavaScript's so sloppy with letting errors slide you don't really want to make it any more so.

Comment: Another mishap is forgetting `var` when assigning to `self`. IE *hates* this.

Comment: Yeah, good old IE and its assign-to-window-property fun. Still, at least it throws an error to let you know you've Done A Bad Practice. Even if the error message is hopelessly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

There's an orange in your apple basket there, `this` has a very specific contextual meaning.  The choice is really between `self` and `me` of those options.  Between those...you choose, it doesn't matter either way only personal preference.

`this` refers to the context your in, so it's not really an "option" without introducing a lot of confusion and easy to make errors.  I see `self` used much more than `me` (in example code, frameworks, libraries, etc).  It's just preference, but I agree `self` is more attractive, not sure why...again just *my* preference.

Comment: I like `me` cause it's two less letters to type... but it really doesn't matter as long as you're *consistent*.

Comment: @codeka - great point, consistency is *far* more important than the choice of name here

Comment: Agreed on the consistency point. It may just be that the choice betrays a programmer's experience of other languages. `self` is Delphi's version of `this` and `me` is VB's version. As far as I know, `that` isn't used in any other language.

Comment: I know what `this` means. I asked about `self`, `me` and **`that`**.

Comment: @Török - I posted before the edited title :) I would steer clear of `that`, at least for a person used to english it would be more confusing (due to the automatic association outside programming).  If your native language isn't english then the association between `this` and `that` won't interfere and it's not as confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Well personally I'm trying to get better at making the variable mean something a little more than "that thing I need later".  Often you need those temporary variables in situations that get a little gnarly; there might be two or more layers of temporary `this` stashes to keep track of.

Thus, for example in a jQuery setup, I might use something to note the element type that a temporary `this` stash should hold:

```
$('form').each(function() {
  var $form = $(this);
  $form.find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    // ...
  });
});
```

Using the "$" prefix on the variables is a nice way to keep track of whether the object has been "jQuery-ized" or not :-)