# Need reference to this is dojo widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, scope, this

```
dojo.declare("profile.BasicInfo", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
  somefunc: function() {
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url: ajaxURL,
        content: adata,
        load: function(data) {
            alert(this);//this refers to the object sent to xhrPost
        }
    });
  },
  somevar: 17
});
```

the place where I used `this` refers to the object im sending as parameter to the function xhrPost. This is correct. No errors. But I want to access the object that is the third parameter to dojo.declare.

or I want to access `somevar` . surely `this.somevar` wont work.

One possible solution that I came up with is to use a duplicate reference to `this` and then use it inside xhrPost. Will this work ? Or am I using the Objects in a wrong way. Or will this give problem when the dojo loader parses the file ?

```
somefunc: function() {
  var temp = this;
  dojo.xhrPost({
      url: ajaxURL,
      content: adata,
      load: function(data) {
          alert(temp);//will temp refer to what i want it to?
      }
  });
},
```

Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698831/that-self-or-me-which-one-to-prefer-in-javascript) and because it's a Douglas Crockford [convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), I prefer to use:

```
var that = this;
```

Answer (score 3):

**dojo.hitch Would look nicer**

Inline anonymous functions are the pain... Try to avoid usage of nesting like declare(.., { foo: new Stuff({ func1: function() { xhr.send({load: function() { **}})})})**;

but in your case, *temp* Does reference 'this'

the prettier would be

```
on: function() {
  xhr.send({
   load: lang.hitch(this, then)
  });
},
then: function(data, io) {
  alert(typeof this.on == "function" + "==true");
}
```

Comment: Not only does it look nicer, but it's less prone to error when `this` _always_ means `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Your example solution is exactly how it's done. Many people use the convention of naming the variable to be bound 'self'.

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: You can also use `dojo.hitch()` for changing the scope of `this`. But i prefer the `var self = this` line by myself. It is less code and more clear.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that one. Personally, I never use hitch, because I think it confuses people with limited dojo experience.