# Chrome browser ignores var self = this;

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, this, undefined, self

I'm writing some jQuery javascript code and was debugging an issue in Google Chrome (latest stable 24 on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion) when I found that

```
MyWidget = Widget.extend({
        _item_id : undefined,
        container : undefined,
        initialize : function(config) {
            var self = this;
            self.container = $(config.container_id);
            self._item_id = config.item_id;
            if (typeof(config.changeElement) !== 'undefined') {
                self._changeElement = config.changeElement;
                $(self._changeElement).unbind('change', OtherWidget.has_setting_changed);

                $(self._changeElement).change(function (event) {
                         self.changeSetting($(event.target).val()); // had 'this' here before
                });

                self._load();
            }
        },
        _load : function() {
            var self = this;  // <-- here is what fails
            self.changeState('Loading');
            if (typeof(self._item_id) === 'undefined' || this._item_id === '') {
                self.changeState('Create');
            } else {
                self._loadItem();
            }
        },

        changeSetting : function(item_id) {
                this._item_id = item_id;
                this._load();
                this._reloadOtherWidget();
        },
...
});
```

showed in the debugger: "self: undefined". The assignment was inside a member function, if that makes any difference. I ended up just using 'this' directly, since it was simple code. I know I'm clobbering ('shadowing') some kind of built-in reference to the window, but I thought it would work... Am I dealing with a known issue?

I saw this related post which seemed to indicate it would work:
[that, self or me — which one to prefer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698831/that-self-or-me-which-one-to-prefer-in-javascript)

Comment: Could we see more code ? If possible a fiddle ? Is this code in strict mode ?

Comment: You need to show your code. To do `var self = this;`, you need to do it in the proper variable scope that encompasses the function where `self` will be used. Since you said it's in a "member function", that makes me think you're expecting `self` to show up in some other function, like a constructor or a prototyped method.

Comment: ...also, are you coding in *strict mode*? If so, the default value of `this` will be `undefined`. Chrome defines a global `self`, so I'm guessing this may rather be a strict mode issue.

Comment: Try naming the variable `that` instead of `self`, so you're not shadowing [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self).

Comment: Thanks -- I specifically want to know if 'self' should work or if Chrome has a known issue with it.

Comment: The latest stable build of Chrome is Chrome 24, not 23. I myself prefer the developer's build, which is two versions ahead at v26.

Comment: In the `_load` method, do `console.log(this, self)` right before and after the `var self = this;` and let us know what shows up in the console.

Comment: @DonovanGlover -- thanks, checked and fixed the version, I had not noticed the change. I update frequently and don't pay much attention. I'm using latest stable.

Comment: does it fail during the invocation of initialize or at some later time when change() is invoked on the _change_element object? - need more information about the context where _load is invoked when it fails

Comment: I think it actually failed on a later change event. I'm actually having trouble reproducing the problem -- should have saved a copy of the problematic version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point where you put

```
         var self = this;  // <-- here is what fails
```

it's already too late : you're in the function you call.

You could do this :

```
MyWidget = Widget.extend((function(){
       var self = {
           _item_id : undefined,
          container : undefined
        };
        self.initialize = function(config) {
            self.container = $(config.container_id);
            self._item_id = config.item_id;
            if (typeof(config.changeElement) !== 'undefined') {
                self._changeElement = config.changeElement;

                self._load();
            }
        };
        self._load = function() {
            self.changeState('Loading');
            if (typeof(self._item_id) === 'undefined' || this._item_id === '') {
                self.changeState('Create');
            } else {
                self._loadItem();
            }
        };
       return self;
})());
```

Comment: Thanks! I added more context because I think I failed to give enough information. Your solution is helpful, but I think I made another mistake.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it is the closest to what I believe is going on -- there is some error of scope. I ended up switching to using 'this' for most of the code.